# Class of differentiable functions and Lipschitz continuity

Tags: integration, convex-analysis

I am reading lectures notes by Dr. Yuvi Nesterov's "Introductory Lectures on Convex Programming ". On page 25, Lemma 1.2.2, to prove $f''(x) \leq L$, (where $f(x) \in C_L^{2,1}(R^n)$, $L$ is Lipschitz constant), he writes:

\begin{equation}
 f'(y)=f'(x) + \int_0^1f''(x+t(y-x))(y-x)dt 
\end{equation}
Can somebody give me big picture of the r.h.s of the above equation, i.e., what does it mean intuitively? How $f'(y)$ can be written as such?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus. Specifically, we can define $g(t)=f'(x+t(y-x))$, so then by FTOC:

$$
g(1) = g(0) + \int_0^1 g'(t) dt
$$

This is equivalent to the given equation since:
$$
\begin{aligned}
g(1)&=f'(y)\\
g(0)&=f'(x)\\
g'(t) &= f''(x+t(y-x))(y-x)
\end{aligned}
$$
So if you want some intuition behind it look at any calculus text that explains the fundamental theorem in an intuitive way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the zero order Taylor expansion for $f'$ at $x$ with an integral form of the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder).